# How to extract 'for' loop Method?

Tags: java, refactoring

I am attempting to  extract my 'for' loop in order to call it in `printPartyBreakdownInHouse()` method. Basically removing any chance of duplicate code or "code smell" as well as my `printdetails()` method, but when doing this I'm getting '2' as a result. Any ideas?

```
public void printPartyBreakdownInSenate() {
    int numDemocrats = 0;
    int numRepblican = 0;
    int numIndepent = 0;

    String senateData;
    ArrayList<MemberOfCongress> members;


    senateData = CongressDataFetcher.fetchSenateData(congressNum);
    members = parseMembersOfCongress(senateData);

    for (MemberOfCongress party : members){
            if (party.getParty().equals("D")){
                numDemocrats++;
            }
            else if (party.getParty().equals("R")){
                numRepblican++;
            }
            else if (party.getParty().equals("I")){
                numIndepent++;
           }
   }
   pintDetails(numIndepent, numIndepent, numIndepent, numIndepent, members);
}

/**
 * printDetails method
 */
void pintDetails(int congressNum, int numDemocrats, int numRepblican, int numIndepent, ArrayList<MemberOfCongress> members){
    System.out.println("Number of Members of the Senate of the " +  congressNum + " Congress : " + members.size() );
    System.out.println("# of Democrats: " + numDemocrats);
    System.out.println("# of Republican: " + numRepblican);
    System.out.println("# of Indep: " + numIndepent);
}

/**
 * Calculate and print the number of Democrats, Republicans, and Independents in this House
 */
public void printPartyBreakdownInHouse(){
    String houseData;
    ArrayList<MemberOfCongress> members;
    houseData = CongressDataFetcher.fetchHouseData(congressNum);
    members = parseMembersOfCongress(houseData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a method which accepts the `members` list as parameter and returns the member counts via an additional helper class as follows:

```
class MemberCounter {
  int numDemocrats;
  int numRepblican;
  int numIndepent;
};

MemberCounter countMembers(List<MemberOfCongress> members) {
  MemberCounter counter = new MemberCounter();

  for (MemberOfCongress party : members) {
    if (party.getParty().equals("D")) {
      counter.numDemocrats++;
    }
    else if (party.getParty().equals("R")){
      counter.numRepblican++;
    }
    else if (party.getParty().equals("I")){
      counter.numIndepent++;
    }
  }

  return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
pintDetails(numIndepent, numIndepent, numIndepent, numIndepent, members);
```

You are printing numIndepent 4 times...?

Comment: I'd like to add because @wisenhiemer seems to be a novice, that the name of the parameters in the method declaration are irrelevant when you call the method, in case maybe OP thought that because it was called `numDemocrats` in one place it was using the variable with the same name in the other method.

Answer (score 1):

The line

`pintDetails(numIndepent, numIndepent, numIndepent, numIndepent, members);`

should read

`pintDetails( [VARIABLE NOT IN CODE], numDemocrats, numRepblican, numIndepent, members);`